# ASP.NET Release jQuery Included Twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, nuget

So, I have an ASP.NET project, and in Debug mode, I get the following line in my HTML source:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
```

However, when I deploy the project, my site has the following line in the source:

```
<script src="/bundles/jquery?v=Ww-VxqepLI91N7FDR1JXgRvM347mWv5Bv_0D4LsyGEk1"></script>
```

I assume this has to do with the bundling/minification. This is normal. What is not normal is that even though I'm trying to use jQuery 2.2.4, the bundled/minified jQuery source seems to contain both jQuery 2.2.4 and 3.0.0 (I verified this by opening the page and noticing multiple copies of the same functions, including the version number). As such, my site's JavaScript is failing, saying that Bootstrap requires jQuery >= 1.9.1 and < 3.0.0.

For the life of me, I can't figure out where this additional jQuery file is coming from.

References.js:

```
/// <autosync enabled="true" />
/// <reference path="bootstrap.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js" />
/// <reference path="jquery-2.2.4.min.js" />
/// <reference path="modernizr-2.8.3.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.matchmedia.addlistener.min.js" />
/// <reference path="respond.min.js" />
```

NuGet (limited to jQuery results):

```
jQuery                                    v2.2.4
    No dependencies.
jQuery.Validation                         v1.15.0
    jQuery (>= 1.4.4)
Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation   v3.2.3
    jQuery (>= 1.8.0)
    jQuery.Validation (>= 1.8.0)
```

packages.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<packages>
  <package id="Antlr" version="3.5.0.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="bootstrap" version="3.3.6.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="EntityFramework" version="6.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jQuery" version="2.2.4" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="jQuery.Validation" version="1.15.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc" version="5.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Razor" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.Web.Optimization" version="1.1.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.AspNet.WebPages" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.CodeDom.Providers.DotNetCompilerPlatform" version="1.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.jQuery.Unobtrusive.Validation" version="3.2.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Net.Compilers" version="1.3.2" targetFramework="net46" developmentDependency="true" />
  <package id="Microsoft.Web.Infrastructure" version="1.0.0.0" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Modernizr" version="2.8.3" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Newtonsoft.Json" version="9.0.1" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="Respond" version="1.4.2" targetFramework="net46" />
  <package id="WebGrease" version="1.6.0" targetFramework="net46" />
</packages>
```

As far as I can tell, all of the dependencies are satisfied. I guess it's possible that one of these packages is trying to include jQuery 3.

Any help would be appreciated. I've tried uninstalling and reinstalling jQuery and related libraries a few times. If any other information is necessary, just let me know!

**Edit:**

The result of disabling bundling is as follows. The HTML page now has:

```
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.6.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/modernizr-2.8.3.js"></script>

... and ...

<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-2.2.4.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-3.0.0.js"></script>
```

Any ideas what is causing this?

Comment: Have you tried disabling bundling, viewing the source code, and going through each `<script>` file individually?  As far as I'm aware, minification/bundling will never add files that are not included in the non-minified versions.  Although it might reference `script.min.js` in place of `script.js` (if a '.min.js' version is present)

Comment: @MartinHansenLennox I have updated my OP to include the result of disabling bundling. The issue seems even worse than I thought. Also, sorry if my comments spammed you; I was trying to format code in this comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the issue by changing my publish settings to:

```
Remove additional files at destination (probably the real solution)
Precompile during publishing
```

It's annoying that other files would be included even though the project settings don't really reference them. I guess bundles.Add was including all jquery/modernizr files matching the wildcard/"version" pattern.